# Sigma BC 500 bike computer "SET MPH"

Tags: bike-computer

I changed the battery in my Sigma BC 500 and it only displays flashing SET MPH. How do I stop this?

Comment: My guess is it's going through the setup process, and is asking you to choose between mile/hour (MPH) and kilometers/hour (KMH).

Answer (score 2):

Changing the battery has very likely reset the memory of the bike computer, so it needs to know what units you want to use, and what tyre size you have on the bike etc. You can even tell it what your old mileage total was so it starts counting from where you left off. I guess that’s how the world managed before Strava ;)

If you still have the manual you should refer to the setup process in it.

If you don’t have the manual, there are copies online you should be able to search for, as well as videos showing how it can be done. Whilst the video I watched was informative and matched the manual for a bc500, it sounds a bit different to what you are seeing, but the process will be very similar.

This video might be helpful:

Comment: Be  aware that on older computer of the time, keys may become sticky (Think drops from bidons!) and not respond very well to pressure and may become hard to set values.

Answer (score 2):

I have a BC 500 and found your post while looking for an answer to the same question. In case anyone else has the same issue, press the big button at the bottom to change option. There is a small button on the reverse side of the computer. Press this button with a pen or pencil to select option.